# lost the right-click "new" context menu entry for office Word 2007. How do I recover it?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

In Windows 7/Ultimate – somehow or another the right-click/new entry on the desktop no longer includes an entry for an Office Word 2007 document. How do I go about adding it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to follow the guidelines from Microsoft here: ["How to add an Object to the New Object List"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140333). It involves editing the Registry, shouldn't be too hard, though.

I guess a safer way would be to just reinstall Office as it shouldn't delete any preferences but just restore everything.

Comment: well,I tried playing with the registry. No luck. So I just reinstalled from a recent download from MSDN and entered into "Repair Mode"– and that worked like a champ. Problem solved!